# Any way to get preview frames while recording video?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I want to stream video to a server and record it on the device at the same time.

If I'm not recording the video I can use Camera.onPreviewCallback where I get the preview data as a byte array and I send the data to the server.

When I start recording though (I'm using MediaRecorder) then onPreviewCallback is called no more.

How can I still obtain the frames from the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting preview callbacks at the same time as recording video is not currently supported by the camera API.

On the latest Android versions, you could use a SurfaceTexture for your preview output, and read the textures back from the GPU to send to your server, instead of using the preview callbacks.

Comment: Thank you. How do I read the textures back from the GPU then? I've already set up a TextureView instead of a SurfaceView but how do I proceed from that?

Comment: You can't do it directly with a TextureView, since it manages its own OpenGL context internally.  

You need to create your own OpenGL context, create a SurfaceTexture with a texture ID of your choosing, render the texture to a frame buffer, and then read it back with glReadPixels. So it's not trivial by any means.